# echo %path% is not working in windows 8

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-8, environment-variables

[image]

Could someone please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Open up the "Environment Variables" in your PC and check the value of JAVA HOME. Make sure it is pointing to the right Java JDK directory

Comment: in documentation, the `<something>` syntax is used to signal to enter something, not the word "something" (and of course without the `<` and `>`). So if the docu says `add <java home> to the path`, you are not supposed to add that exact string, but the home directory of your java installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem would appear to be `<Java Home>`.

`echoing` this would attempt to read from a file named `Java`.

In all probability, you need to change it to `%java home%`

Comment: thx alot!!!! But why? (sry cause i'm nooby); I know %***% is for variable, what about <***>.

Comment: `<` redirects input, `>` redirects output. The `path` variable should be an ordered, semicolon-separated list of directories that windows searches to find an executable if the executable isn't found in the current directory. If you `echo` the variable `%path%` then `%path%` is replaced by its value and *then* the `echo` is executed. Since it contains redirectors, the `echo` will try to read from the `<filename` and write to the `>filename`. `Echo` doesn't read, but it does write, but you've specified `<filename` so it will first assign that file to be read regardless. It doesn't exist,so error